# Where is DataTable class in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, namespaces, uwp

I knew the **System.Data** namespace was missing from WinRT so my hope for programming based on DataTable or DataSet for WinRT was never raised. Now I see the System.Data (and System.Data.Common) namespace in UWP, but DataTable or DataSet is never to be found. Or, am I missing something, or need a different namespace?

More specifically, if I used **System.Data.DataTable** and **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable** in the past, what do I need to do to migrate the old code to UWP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The datatable does not exist in UWP.  You should look at using EF7 for data access.  You will not be able to automate excel from a UWP app.   Syncfusion has a XlsIo library for interacting with excel.

https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/uwp.html

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio

Check out there community license

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. If I need an in-memory datatable like data object, do you know any class that help such a data structure? I'm assuming that EF7 doesn't have a DataTable type. Sorry I don't mean to tag another question.

Comment: No Microsoft has been moving away from the data table for quite a while.  The current recommendation is to store the data in a list or observable collection.

Comment: Thanks again and that explains why my search for UWP DataTable was not returning any results. But, makes me wonder, why kill off such a useful data handling class?